# Plotting a subplot- Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, datetimeindex

I have been trying to achieve something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg6V9.jpg)

So far this is what I have tried:

```
crimes.Month = pd.to_datetime(crimes.Month, format='%Y/%m')

crimes.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(crimes.Month)

import numpy as np

crimes_count_date = crimes.pivot_table('Month', aggfunc=np.size,columns='Crime type', index=crimes.index.date, fill_value=0)

crimes_count_date.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(crimes_count_date.index)

plo = crimes_count_date.rolling(365).sum().plot(figsize=(12, 30),subplots=True, layout=(-1, 3), sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

Note- on the x-axis I would like to display each year/month: 2017/08

Current output below, is not showing all months/year or any lines for the crime types
[Current Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft2kw.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your data looks.

But python has a nice way of doing subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8)) ## setting over-all figure size (optional)
plt.subplot(2, 3, 1) 

##  this creates 6 subplots (2 rows and 3 columns)
## 1 at the end means we are in the first subplot.. then...

plt.plot(x1,y1) ## for well-selected x1 and y1
plt.subplot(232) ## the same as subplot(2, 3, 2) - you can use this when values have
                 ## one digit only; now we are in the 2nd subplot
plt.plot(x2, y2)  ## this will be plotted in the second subplot

## etc. ...

plt.subplot(236)
plt.plot(x6,y6)
```